# How should I answer a question of someone else in  Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

How should I answer a question of someone else in Stack Overflow?

I came across this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cimg+fftw

and wanted to answer:

> you can define cimg_use_fftw3 before including CImg, i.e.
>
> ```
> #define cimg_use_fftw3 1
> #include "CImgpp.h"
> ```
>
> Then Cimg will use the fftw3 FFT instead of it's own version which only allows for 2^n-sized (i.e. 1,2,...,1024,2048, etc) inputs. Then call the FFT() method of the CImg struct:
>
> http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html#aab0887ae7c3bd1571ea7ccc4a8cac3f6

Comment: Go answer that question.  Don't create a new question.  There's a big text box underneath the question.

Comment: Are you asking how to actually submit an answer, or whether your proposed answer is acceptable, or something else?

Answer (score 5):

You're talking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114324/fft-of-an-image)?

The filled-in green check next to @CookieOfFortune's answer indicates that the question is **already answered**. If you still want to answer it, just type your answer in the "Your Answer" box.

[image]

Comment: I have that font too: "Paintbrush Gothica Narrow"

Comment: I wonder if my answer got 4 upvotes so that it would look just like the picture (and further confuse the OP).

Answer (score 1):

Scroll down to the bottom of the page. Where it says "Your Answer" and and has a large textarea is where you would post your answer.

And you can format your code by highlighting it and pressing the { } button.